# Get generic type class name at run time

Tags: java, reflection

My application is throwing

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
```

For this code:

```
public class DsMap<K,V> implements Map<K, V>{
    protected Class<K> kClazz;
    protected Class<V> vClazz;  

    // Called during DS.getMap(mapName) method
    public DsMap(String name) {
        ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        Type typeK = genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        Type typeV = genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[1];

        if (typeK instanceof Class) {
            this.kClazz = (Class<K>) typeK;
        } else if (typeK instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            this.kClazz = (Class<K>) ((ParameterizedType)typeK).getRawType();
        }

        if (typeV instanceof Class) {
            this.vClazz = (Class<V>) typeV;
        } else if (typeV instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            this.vClazz = (Class<V>) ((ParameterizedType)typeV).getRawType();
        }           
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the class name of `K` and `V` at runtime:

Such that doing this:

```
Map<String,String> dsMap = DS.getMap(mapName);
```

I will get `java.lang.String` for the class names of `kClazz` and `vClazz`, or get whatever class name parameterized (without instantiating `Class<K>` and `Class<V>`)

What could be wrong in my code?

Comment: For this approach to work, you have to make `DsMap` abstract and instantiate it with real types, e.g. `new DsMap<Integer, Integer>(){}`.

Comment: You might find it useful to look at the documentation and implementation of [`TypeToken` in Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html).

Answer (score 1):

A parameterized type represents a *concrete* realization of a generic type. You can think of the relationship between a generic and parameterized type in the same way you think of the relationship between a *template* and a *document*. A template tells you where you would fill in information, a document has the information actually filled in. In your example:

```
public class DsMap<K,V> implements Map<K, V>
```

Both `DsMap` and `Map` are generic types (or templates). Their actual generic parameters are not specified by the class itself, and as such, are not captured by the compiler. In other words, their generic information is not available at run time.

In order to capture actual generic parameters at run time, those parameters would need to be part of the class signature. For example, this simple extension of your class would work:

```
public class DsMapIntegerString extends DsMap<Integer, String>
```

Because you've provided concrete parameters, the type returned by `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` will actually be a parameterized class, and your code will no longer fail.

Answer (score 0):

`DsMap` implements a generic interface (`Map<K,V>`), but it doesn't extend a generic class. So `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` returns a reference to `java.lang.Object`, which can't be cast to `ParameterizedType`.

The `(ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` trick only applies when 
1) The subclass extends a generic class
2) The subclass declares its type arguments at compile time

e.g.:

```
public abstract class DsMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {
```

...

```
public class StringIntDsMap extends DsMap<String, Integer> {
```

...

Then, `getGenericSuperclass()` would return `DsMap`, which could be cast to `ParameterizedType`, and the entries in the `Type[]` array returned from `getActualTypeArguments()` could be cast to `Class`.

Unfortunately, this isn't a very widespread condition. I've used it frequently to share code between unit tests (where I can declare the generic types at compile time). But it doesn't generalize to the case where types are unavailable until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Visual inspection says try changing:

```
static public class DsMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {
```

To

```
static public class DsMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
```